# IdentityServer 4 login with username or phone number

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid

In our product, we have mobile app interact with API which auth against  `IdentityServer 4`,
the business set a requirement to be able to login using a phone(SMS auth) or username auth for the same person.
I found this example project in order to login with phone SMS and it works great:
`IdentityServer4.PhoneNumberAuth`

How can I combine a username login as well?

Comment: How the identityserver4 authenticates the user is about how you want to create the cookie session on your identityserver4 application. It does not have much to do with oidc or oauth. oidc and oauth are about how the third party application that initiated the login request get access to apis and stuff in behalf the user by using a bearer token most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UserStore inheriting from IUserStore. Refer the below code snippet to login with either username or email or phone number.

```
public partial class UserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    //Other method implementation 

    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindByNameAsync(string normalizedUserName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (normalizedUserName == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(normalizedUserName));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(authDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.NormalizedUserName == normalizedUserName
        || u.PhoneNumber == normalizedUserName || u.NormalizedEmail == normalizedUserName));
    }
}
```